# Travelling from Mumbai to Amsterdam, with a transit in France. Can I shop duty free in Mumbai?

Tags: transit, duty-free, mumbai

Normally, I wouldn't consider shopping Duty Free with a transit flight. But since this transit is within the EU, I wonder if it might be possible to carry some alcohol from the Mumbai Duty-Free. Your perspectives will be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not do that. For example I used to take flights within Shengen area to / from Sweden and the alcohol was limited to 1 litter per person.
Overall I don't really get the point of buying in Duty free shops in Mumbai and not in Amsterdam considering the local products are not as traditionals as the ones you can buy in the country itself.